# ArcGIS & historical versions performance expectations

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, versioning

Short background: ArcGIS Server 10.1.1 Enterprise edition using MSSQL for our RDBMS.

Currently we utilize versioning only to support replication between 2 databases (edit to DEFAULT). Of late, I'm being asked more and more about the potential for producing 'snapshots' in time. Of course, ESRI supports historical based versions, but I get the sense that this is more for project-level management...not long term management, mostly because for performance reasons, you'll need to be reconciling versions, etc. We also conduct many many edits even on a given day; this DB is constantly updated.

Questions therefore are:

1. Am I interpreting the ESRI documentation correctly in terms of historical versions not being long-term data management strategies?
2. Are there other options I should be looking at to support this request for historical data modeling/tracking/archiving?
3. For those using ESRI's archiving: what has your performance been like? How long have you sustained historical versions for?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Although related, to fit the Q&A format of GIS SE, I recommend you pose this as three separate questions.

Comment: @PolyGeo: do you think that these are unrelated enough to warrant 3 separate questions? I don't want to create an unnecessary volume of questions if possible. I could attempt to just winnow this down to my most important question: #1. Do you suggest that instead?

Comment: Asking the question which is the most important to you first seems like a good strategy. As that gets answered and commented upon you may well find that the "less important" questions get resolved for you too.